# Assign Column values in groups of 3 - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, assign

I'm aiming to `assign` places to people in a `pandas` `df`. Specifically, using the `df` below I determine how many places are currently *on*. I want to use these values and `assign` them in groups of 3.

For instance, total places occurring that are less than 3 should be assigned to `P1`. Places that are 3-6 should be assigned to `P2` etc.

**Note: The total number of places occurring at once can go up to 20 so the number of assigned groups need to accomodate for this.**

Here is my attempt.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({
    'Time' : ['8:03:00','8:07:00','8:10:00','8:23:00','8:27:00','8:30:00','8:37:00','8:40:00','8:48:00'],                 
    'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 3','House 4','House 5','House 1','House 2','House 3','House 4'],                                     
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['u'] = df[::-1].groupby('Place').Place.cumcount()
ids = [1]
seen = set([df.iloc[0].Place])
dec = False
for val, u in zip(df.Place[1:], df.u[1:]):
    ids.append(ids[-1] + (val not in seen) - dec)
    seen.add(val)
    dec = u == 0
df['Places On'] = ids

df = df.drop(df[['u']], axis=1)

def g(gps):
        s = gps['Place'].unique()
        d = dict(zip(s, np.arange(len(s)) // 3 + 1))
        gps['P'] = gps['Place'].map(d)
        return gps

df = df.groupby('Place', sort=False).apply(g)
```

Output:

```
      Time    Place  Places On  P
0  8:03:00  House 1          1  1
1  8:07:00  House 2          2  1
2  8:10:00  House 3          3  1
3  8:23:00  House 4          4  1
4  8:27:00  House 5          5  1
5  8:30:00  House 1          4  1
6  8:37:00  House 2          3  1
7  8:40:00  House 3          2  1
8  8:48:00  House 4          1  1
```

Intended Output:

```
      Time    Place  Places On  P
0  8:03:00  House 1          1  1
1  8:07:00  House 2          2  1
2  8:10:00  House 3          3  1
3  8:23:00  House 4          4  2
4  8:27:00  House 5          5  2
5  8:30:00  House 1          4  2
6  8:37:00  House 2          3  1
7  8:40:00  House 3          2  1
8  8:48:00  House 4          1  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({
    'Time' : ['8:03:00','8:07:00','8:10:00','8:23:00','8:27:00','8:30:00','8:37:00','8:40:00','8:48:00'],                 
    'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 3','House 4','House 5','House 1','House 2','House 3','House 4'],                                     
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['u'] = df[::-1].groupby('Place').Place.cumcount()
ids = [1]
seen = set([df.iloc[0].Place])
dec = False
for val, u in zip(df.Place[1:], df.u[1:]):
    ids.append(ids[-1] + (val not in seen) - dec)
    seen.add(val)
    dec = u == 0
df['Places On'] = ids

df = df.drop(df[['u']], axis=1)

def g(gps):
        s = gps['Place'].unique()
        d = dict(zip(s, np.arange(len(s)) // 3 + 1))
        gps['P'] = gps['Place'].map(d)
        return gps

df = df.groupby('Place', sort=False).apply(g)

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if(df['Places On'][i]<=3):
        df['P'][i]=1
    else:
        df['P'][i]=2
print(df)
```

This should work based on sorting df['Places On'].

Comment: Gotimulul, this needs to be more dynamic sorry. The number of places occurring can go up to 20. Therefore the assigned groups need to accomodate for this.